# Any thoughts on how I could parse this text file to get a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing, dplyr, tidyverse

I am having trouble creating a data frame with the following made up data in a text file, although the free text is the same. I know it's really messy...

```
<Annotations><Annotation LineColor="255" Name="Trial for orientation" Visible="True"><Regions><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4541" Y="1558" /><V X="4724" Y="1799" /></Vertices></Region></Regions></Annotation><Annotation LineColor="65280" Name="vRNA+ cells" Visible="True"><Regions><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4379" Y="1790" /><V X="4390" Y="1799" /></Vertices></Region></Regions></Annotation><Annotation LineColor="65280" Name="vRNA+ cells" Visible="True"><Regions><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4386" Y="1828" /><V X="4397" Y="1837" /></Vertices></Region></Regions></Annotation><Annotation LineColor="65280" Name="vRNA+ cells" Visible="True"><Regions><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6493" Y="5094" /><V X="6504" Y="5106" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3812" Y="3623" /><V X="3825" Y="3637" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5929" Y="4178" /><V X="5945" Y="4194" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6625" Y="2950" /><V X="6657" Y="2978" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4558" Y="4108" /><V X="4573" Y="4123" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4790" Y="3634" /><V X="4813" Y="3662" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4518" Y="3659" /><V X="4531" Y="3671" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4605" Y="3672" /><V X="4624" Y="3694" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5402" Y="5809" /><V X="5414" Y="5822" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5950" Y="4281" /><V X="5976" Y="4308" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6874" Y="3009" /><V X="6892" Y="3025" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5747" Y="5081" /><V X="5771" Y="5107" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6252" Y="2950" /><V X="6269" Y="2966" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5849" Y="2824" /><V X="5870" Y="2837" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5928" Y="4387" /><V X="5942" Y="4399" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5687" Y="6327" /><V X="5707" Y="6340" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6752" Y="1357" /><V X="6778" Y="1372" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5354" Y="4828" /><V X="5377" Y="4847" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="7917" Y="3164" /><V X="7940" Y="3175" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="7912" Y="3149" /><V X="7928" Y="3163" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6297" Y="3778" /><V X="6313" Y="3799" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="7084" Y="3362" /><V X="7101" Y="3379" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4970" Y="5380" /><V X="4982" Y="5395" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3445" Y="1445" /><V X="3457" Y="1456" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6426" Y="5157" /><V X="6436" Y="5171" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5376" Y="1552" /><V X="5397" Y="1570" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4577" Y="2321" /><V X="4609" Y="2346" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2637" Y="2264" /><V X="2664" Y="2288" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6650" Y="1357" /><V X="6671" Y="1378" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="8594" Y="3417" /><V X="8611" Y="3437" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2988" Y="2342" /><V X="3006" Y="2356" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4986" Y="2410" /><V X="5000" Y="2420" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="7647" Y="5031" /><V X="7662" Y="5044" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6844" Y="2660" /><V X="6858" Y="2670" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5284" Y="3289" /><V X="5304" Y="3308" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2681" Y="2457" /><V X="2707" Y="2483" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4648" Y="3349" /><V X="4662" Y="3361" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2233" Y="1564" /><V X="2247" Y="1579" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6117" Y="4809" /><V X="6144" Y="4833" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5478" Y="6361" /><V X="5494" Y="6374" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5489" Y="6427" /><V X="5497" Y="6436" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5472" Y="6476" /><V X="5481" Y="6487" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5471" Y="6440" /><V X="5485" Y="6458" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="7226" Y="4961" /><V X="7237" Y="4975" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4725" Y="6452" /><V X="4745" Y="6470" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6949" Y="2462" /><V X="6972" Y="2479" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5000" Y="2420" /><V X="5006" Y="2428" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2089" Y="4001" /><V X="2104" Y="4016" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2958" Y="3938" /><V X="2968" Y="3953" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4854" Y="6259" /><V X="4873" Y="6276" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5420" Y="4202" /><V X="5441" Y="4227" /></Vertices></Region></Regions></Annotation><Annotation LineColor="16777215" Name="FDC trapped virus" Visible="True"><Regions><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5416" Y="1480" /><V X="5536" Y="1576" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5695" Y="3512" /><V X="5767" Y="3611" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="1897" Y="1636" /><V X="2093" Y="1888" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4770" Y="2430" /><V X="4846" Y="2531" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5192" Y="1246" /><V X="5306" Y="1441" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4776" Y="1457" /><V X="4878" Y="1586" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="1669" Y="1563" /><V X="1794" Y="1617" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4096" Y="1504" /><V X="4195" Y="1591" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4544" Y="1566" /><V X="4719" Y="1788" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3905" Y="1350" /><V X="3971" Y="1426" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5302" Y="3416" /><V X="5369" Y="3479" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6100" Y="2670" /><V X="6240" Y="2822" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6090" Y="2919" /><V X="6247" Y="3010" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3145" Y="2292" /><V X="3268" Y="2426" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3207" Y="1841" /><V X="3424" Y="1955" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3522" Y="1510" /><V X="3717" Y="1751" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3838" Y="1661" /><V X="4054" Y="1865" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5897" Y="961" /><V X="6000" Y="1060" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5746" Y="1319" /><V X="5965" Y="1529" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4948" Y="1375" /><V X="5146" Y="1536" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6806" Y="2219" /><V X="6924" Y="2334" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2984" Y="2411" /><V X="3026" Y="2470" /></Vertices></Region></Regions></Annotation><Annotation LineColor="16711935" Name="Artifact" Visible="True"><Regions><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6407" Y="5169" /><V X="6422" Y="5185" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4959" Y="3499" /><V X="5002" Y="3554" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="8740" Y="4189" /><V X="8787" Y="4238" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5431" Y="4342" /><V X="5470" Y="4371" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="8211" Y="3461" /><V X="8238" Y="3495" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4660" Y="4481" /><V X="4690" Y="4500" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5969" Y="5897" /><V X="5998" Y="5920" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2391" Y="4223" /><V X="2410" Y="4239" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="9055" Y="2277" /><V X="9079" Y="2302" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5446" Y="6683" /><V X="5457" Y="6694" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="8384" Y="1065" /><V X="8401" Y="1081" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="1906" Y="3761" /><V X="1930" Y="3776" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6475" Y="2238" /><V X="6491" Y="2253" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6504" Y="2234" /><V X="6525" Y="2247" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6968" Y="2274" /><V X="6998" Y="2295" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3849" Y="5101" /><V X="3874" Y="5127" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4177" Y="3950" /><V X="4212" Y="3984" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="1906" Y="3311" /><V X="1927" Y="3331" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3358" Y="3828" /><V X="3378" Y="3843" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5421" Y="6670" /><V X="5436" Y="6685" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3669" Y="1428" /><V X="3693" Y="1446" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4982" Y="6011" /><V X="5033" Y="6049" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6113" Y="948" /><V X="6145" Y="971" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3227" Y="1543" /><V X="3251" Y="1562" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="1535" Y="3082" /><V X="1554" Y="3095" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3411" Y="3585" /><V X="3440" Y="3613" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2216" Y="2010" /><V X="2231" Y="2024" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="5223" Y="4131" /><V X="5252" Y="4156" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="4365" Y="4154" /><V X="4391" Y="4174" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6756" Y="4481" /><V X="6792" Y="4513" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="2645" Y="2191" /><V X="2665" Y="2206" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6569" Y="4468" /><V X="6607" Y="4501" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="3246" Y="2027" /><V X="3266" Y="2040" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="7095" Y="1673" /><V X="7113" Y="1685" /></Vertices></Region><Region Type="Rectangle" HasEndcaps="0" NegativeROA="0"><Vertices><V X="6340" Y="3752" /><V X="6362" Y="3780" /></Vertices></Region></Regions></Annotation></Annotations>
```

What I am trying to do is to get a data frame that has two columns of X and Y that are paired as you see in the text. For instance, the first one X and Y would be 4541 and 1558 in the same row followed by 4724 and 1799.

I've tried importing and using "=" as a delimiter but it just creates many columns of data when I really need them within the data frame. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Where did this file come from? Doesn’t look like HTML or XML... maybe try doing some very simple regular expressions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are in XML format, so it would make sense to parse the XML rather than extract features from it as a string.

Here is a simple example, which reads the data you supplied (saved as a XML file) and uses the `xml2` package to go through each `<V />` node, extracts the X and Y coordinates and assembles them into a new tibble, converting the values to integers along the way:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2) 

data <- read_xml("path/to/your/data.xml")

vertices <- xml_find_all(data, "//V")

coordinates <- tibble(
  X = as.integer(xml_attr(vertices, "X")),
  Y = as.integer(xml_attr(vertices, "Y")))
)
```

The result is this:

```
# A tibble: 222 x 2
       X     Y
    
 1  4541  1558
 2  4724  1799
 3  4379  1790
 4  4390  1799
 5  4386  1828
 6  4397  1837
 7  6493  5094
 8  6504  5106
 9  3812  3623
10  3825  3637
# ... with 212 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is structured XML, so you can use XPaths into it to extract the data.

Assume that the data you posted above is in `foo.xml`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

vertices <- read_xml('foo.xml') %>% xml_find_all('.//Vertices')

xy_data <-
    tibble(
        x1 = vertices %>% xml_find_all('./*[1]') %>% xml_attr('X'),
        y1 = vertices %>% xml_find_all('./*[1]') %>% xml_attr('Y'),
        x2 = vertices %>% xml_find_all('./*[2]') %>% xml_attr('X'),
        y2 = vertices %>% xml_find_all('./*[2]') %>% xml_attr('Y')
    ) %>%
    mutate_all(as.integer)

print(xy_data)
# A tibble: 111 x 4
      x1    y1    x2    y2
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1  4541  1558  4724  1799
 2  4379  1790  4390  1799
 3  4386  1828  4397  1837
 4  6493  5094  6504  5106
 5  3812  3623  3825  3637
 6  5929  4178  5945  4194
 7  6625  2950  6657  2978
 8  4558  4108  4573  4123
 9  4790  3634  4813  3662
10  4518  3659  4531  3671
# … with 101 more rows
```